# How to split string properly if there are more than 35 characters in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

I am working with some string to import address inside Sage.
The thing is I need to split my address name if this one contains more than 35 characters, to put the first part inside a variable (max 35 char), and the other one inside another variable.
But instead of just splitting in half, or 35 / 14, it needs to be splitted right before the last space, to keep the address name readable.

For exemple :
34 Right Begun Street, City Of Splitting, Paris France

var 1 = 34 Right Begun Street, City Of

var 2 = Splitting, Paris France
(splitting contains the 35th character, so it needs to be in the last part).

Do you have any idea how to do this with XSLT/Xpath 1.0/Xpath 2.0 ? I've tried by substring-before and substring-after, but I can figure out how to remove right when it needs to be splitted.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xsl:analyze-string` can help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string">^(.{1,35}) (.*$)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern}">
              <xsl:matching-substring>
                  <first-part>
                      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                  </first-part>
                  <second-part>
                      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                  </second-part>
              </xsl:matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4u2

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Martin Honnen Nice solution! Could you please explain how the regex works in this case?

Comment: @Sebastien, the `^` matches the start of the string, the `(.{1,35})` (greedily) matches and captures the 1-35 characters before the space ` ` and `(.*$)` matches and captures the rest after the space.

Comment: Unfortunalty , it doesn't work with WSO2 (the tool I am using for parsing datas) but your response match great if we only talk about xslt. How will you do in Xpath 1.0 ?

Comment: @Robyn.D, the question was and is tagged as XSLT and Saxon, I assumed that to be a Saxon version that at least supports XSLT 2 if not 3 these days. I am not familiar with WSO2, perhaps ask a new question tagged appropriately and someone with expertise in that area can help you out.

Comment: @Robyn.D, WSO2 does support Xpath 2.0 functions. But you need to enable XPath 2.0 since this is disabled by default.
https://medium.com/@isuruuy/using-xpath-2-0-functions-in-wso2-ei-fbb954139cb2

Comment: XPath 2.0 is enabled. The fact is I thought I was using Saxon, but it was Xalan by default. I changed it and it works great now.